# How to spliit a NSString in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a NSString like this.

00:03:45

I want to get only this 03:45 part and show in a `UILabel`

How can I do that? Please help me

Thanks

Comment: You could start by actually reading the documentation for NSString.

Comment: Agreed. Apple's documentation is good enough for most situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this multiple types

assume that this is your String

```
NSString *origialString =@"00:03:45";
```

**Type-1**

```
NSArray *getBalance = [origialString componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];

origialString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [getBalance objectAtIndex:1], [getBalance objectAtIndex:2]];
```

**Type-2**

```
origialString = [origialString substringFromIndex:3];
```

**Type-3**

```
origialString = [origialString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [origialString  length]-3)];
```

**Type-4**

```
// Use NSDateformatter but not necessary for here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *timeParts = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];

NSString *newTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [timeParts objectAtIndex:1], [timeParts objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think in terms of splitting a string, think in terms of formatting your date that happens to be a string. You'll want to use an NSDateFormatter here.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];//Or whatever is applicable for your
NSString *timeString = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSDate dateFromString:yourString];
```

Or, if you really wanted to get a substring from that particular string, you could do this:

```
NSString *subString = [yourString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 7)];
```